# .net assemblies based database

Tags: .net, database, c#-4.0, orm

One of the common tasks in server application development is a retrieving data from database and their mapping to OO language objects. Why we should not store data in the representation, convinient for runtime enviroment? We can create, update, load and unload .net assemblies. Only what we need - is create assembly manager for controlling all assemblies with data(on one machine or in cluster). Reflection works very slowly, I know, but this idea inspired by prolog language-integrated database. Is described database architecture is fit to implementing?

Comment: look into Entity Framework and what it can do for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assemblies only contain the structure (type information) and the code, but not your actual instantiated objects.

If you load an assembly, create an object from a type defined in it, the assembly itself is not modified - the object lives in the process' memory, not in the assembly.

Comment: but how this task was solved in [Sharepoint](http://lightningtools.com/bcs/bcs-shims-net-assembly-as-a-data-source-for-business-connectivity-services/)?